# Composer.phar install doesn't complete when deploying to Azure

Tags: symfony, azure, composer-php

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony app to Microsoft Azure.
I have created a service plan, App, made sure PHP is v5.6 (on which I developed the app locally), added the php_intl.dll extension, pushed files from Git and when running __ php -d extension=php_intl.dll composer.phar install __ after vendor are installed I get the below errors. I run this command in the cloud Kudu command console.

What am I doing wrong? How do I deploy? The guide on Symfony.com is a bit outdated but got me up until this step.

```
Generating autoload files
Deprecation Notice: The callback Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap declared at D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Composer\ScriptHandler.php accepts a Composer\Script\CommandEvent but post-install-cmd events use a Composer\Script\Event instance. Please adjust your type hint accordingly, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-classes in phar://D:/home/site/wwwroot/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:290
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
Deprecation Notice: The callback Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache declared at D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Composer\ScriptHandler.php accepts a Composer\Script\CommandEvent but post-install-cmd events use a Composer\Script\Event instance. Please adjust your type hint accordingly, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-classes in phar://D:/home/site/wwwroot/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:290The symfony-bin-dir (bin) specified in composer.json was not found in D:\home\site\wwwroot, can not clear the cache.
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
Deprecation Notice: The callback Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets declared at D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Composer\ScriptHandler.php accepts a Composer\Script\CommandEvent but post-install-cmd events use a Composer\Script\Event instance. Please adjust your type hint accordingly, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-classes in phar://D:/home/site/wwwroot/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:290
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets
Deprecation Notice: The callback Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile declared at D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Composer\ScriptHandler.php accepts a Composer\Script\CommandEvent but post-install-cmd events use a Composer\Script\Event instance. Please adjust your type hint accordingly, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-classes in phar://D:/home/site/wwwroot/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:290
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile

The symfony-bin-dir (bin) specified in composer.json was not found in D:\home\site\wwwroot, can not install assets.
The symfony-bin-dir (bin) specified in composer.json was not found in D:\home\site\wwwroot, can not install the requirements files.
Deprecation Notice: The callback Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget declared at D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Composer\ScriptHandler.php accepts a Composer\Script\CommandEvent but post-install-cmd events use a Composer\Script\Event instance. Please adjust your type hint accordingly, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#event-classes in phar://D:/home/site/wwwroot/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:290
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget
```

Composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "symfony/console": "^3.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.7",
        "symfony/security": "^3.0",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^2.1",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "^3.3",
        "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "^2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^1.7",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
        "ci/restclientbundle": "^1.0",
        "eightpoints/guzzle-bundle": "^4.4",
        "jasongrimes/paginator": "^1.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.5",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^3.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.6",
        "league/oauth2-client": "^1.4",
        "league/oauth2-facebook": "^1.4"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^2.7"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never deployed on Microsoft Azure but so far it looks like some resources are not where they're expected. Have a look to your composer.json

Comment: Would that make sense if when running composer install locally I don't get the errors? I'll check json too in the meantime

Comment: Could you provide your composer.json file ?

Comment: Could you also provide your phpinfo ?

Comment: That's the even weirder part. When I try to access the website cloud URL I get __You do not have permission to view this directory or page__ and when I try to access /phpinfo.php I get __The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable__ even though the site and service are running. Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: It may come from a misconfiguration have to [microsoft support][1]

Comment: I should contact support?

Comment: It may be a misconfiguration problem. Have look to [microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942042) to solve your permission problem

Comment: Ok, i will reach out to them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128438/discussion-between-olivier-chretien-and-roland-birsan).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your `.gitignore` file has the following so that `composer` knows which requirements need to be installed

```
!bin/console
!bin/symfony_requirements
```

As documented by gitignore/Symfony.gitignore [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Symfony.gitignore)